# Is the discharge rate for all AAA batteries the same?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

Just a simple question regarding battery hype.
Given 10 brands of readily available AAA batteries, is the discharge rate going to differ between them given the same load for the same period of time?

I understand shelf life can differ. But will they all store the same amount of power and discharge it at the same rate?

Thank you. Just a question to assist in judging brand value/$ on use rather than non-use.

---

Added:

All the answers kill the layman theory of “...all built in the same factory, all the same, you’re paying for a name.”

Interesting that eight times more expensive battery brands are not eight times better in performance.

Again, thanks so much for the great answers! Very impressive and most helpful.

Comment: AAA is a form factor, not a technology.  Even just restricting to primary "flashlight" cells there have been various chemistries used.  And even among modern alkaline implementations, things will differ.

Comment: It also depends on the load. For a light load the cheaper cells may do OK; for a heavy load they may die young.

Comment: What they say: Plus: AAA come in "Alkaline" and "Other". Other may call itself "Hi Power" or similar, but who can say what is inside. There are several non-Alkaline chemistries that MAY be present but unless you have documentation and known good source treat other as "cheap and may be useful in some applications". Alkaline comes in "reputable brand" and "unknown brand". It MAY be that unknown brands are in fact good quality - but you'll need to determine that yourself. Maxtor, Eveready, GP (one of the 3 largest battery makers in the world), and quite a few more are dependable. Batteries ...

Comment: ... from them MAY come from the same factories that unknown batteries come from. || Weight is usually a reasonable measure of Alkaline battery "goodness".  Typical quality AAA Alkaline cells weigh 11+ grams. Slightly less MAY be OK. Substantially more is unlikely (and I've not seen one).

Comment: A good test of "is it Alkaline" is to measure open circuit voltage of a new cell. A factory fresh true Alkaline will have Voc of about 1.65V - maybe slightly more. As they age Voc drops but is still usually over 1.6V for 1+ years. At several years maybe 1.55 - 1.6V but probably never under 1.55V for the whole shelf life. Anything new in packet should be over 1.6V. | Modern Alkaline shelf life is now 5+ years (7 claimed on some labels). || Also watch for physical leakage when left discharged. Most do not leak substantially but a brand name cell is (or was) prone to. ||

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked myself much the same question a few years ago. My local very cheap supermarket had an offer on some very expensive name brand AA batteries 'U', so I bought a pack of those, and a pack of their own brand alkaline AAs 'W' at 13% of the name brand price. I also had some own brand cells from a middle-price supermarket 'A', and some rechargable NiMH cells 'N' for comparison. Here is the discharge graph.

[image]

As you can see, the most expensive cells are the best, but not 8 times better. The early drop in voltage on the cheapest cells suggest a higher internal resistance, which means they won't be able to supply the power output of the better cells.

You asked about AAA and I'm presenting results on AA size. They are the same technology and build method. The main difference is that AAs have a higher capacity and power output than AAAs, and have a better ratio of output to weight, size and cost than do AAAs, as their ratio of active chemical to case is better.

To get the best delivered energy from alkaline technology, you will need to work from a wide voltage range. A switching regulator is nearly essential here. Once you have that, then a cheaper cell will simply give you a shorter lifetime.

What you do get with a name brand cell is some sort of assurance that the performance for future purchases of the same type will continue to be as per their datasheet. I was unable to find a datasheet for either of the own brand cells.

Note that this is a sample of one of each type of battery, measured once, at one load resistance. I would not be surprised to see the results rank in the same order at other load resistances, but have not done the measurement.

Shelf life is a rather different parameter, and impossible to measure in one day as I did the discharge curves. It depends on the chemical system chosen for the cell (the same in all cases) and the quality with which that has been implemented (as can be seen from the graph, there is a demonstrated difference in capacity and internal resistance). It's perhaps not unreasonable to hope that there might be better purity of the chemicals, or additional additives to suppress leakage, in the name brand cells. However, without specifications or measurements, that would be just hope.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to give a definitive answer without extensive testing of samples of each brand of battery. I would suspect, though, that the results for name brands such as EverReady and Duracell would show good agreement with their published specifications since they are reputable companies. All bets are off for no-name brands where price is the driving factor. I would suggest that if your application is at all critical you stick to the name brands or. at least, test some samples of the brand you would like to use.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary:**

A non-brand-name cell that is much cheaper than brand name cells is liable to be value for money as long as weight is 11+ grams and Voc is > 1.6V.

---

AAA cells come in "Alkaline" and "Other".
Other may call itself "Hi Power" or similar, but who can say what is inside.
There are several non-Alkaline chemistries that MAY be present but, unless you have documentation and known good source, treat 'other' as "cheap and may be useful in some applications".

Alkaline comes in "reputable brand" and "unknown brand".
It MAY be that unknown brands are in fact good quality - but you'll need to determine that yourself. Duracell, Eveready, GP (one of the 3 largest battery makers in the world), Maxtor, and quite a few more are dependable.

Batteries from them MAY come from the same factories that unknown batteries come from.
Manufacturers can and may tailor cells to suit a client's needs.

**Quality?:**  Weight is usually a reasonable measure of Alkaline battery "goodness". Typical quality AAA Alkaline cells weigh 11+ grams. Slightly less MAY be OK. Substantially more is unlikely (and I've not seen one).

A good test of "is it Alkaline" is to measure open circuit voltage of a new cell.
A factory fresh true Alkaline will have Voc of about 1.65V - maybe slightly more. As they age Voc drops but is still usually over 1.6V for 1+ years. At several years maybe 1.55 - 1.6V but probably never under 1.55V for the whole shelf life. Anything new in packet should be over 1.6V.

Modern Alkaline shelf life is now 5+ years (7 claimed on some labels).

Also watch for physical leakage when left discharged. Most do not leak substantially but a brand name cell is (or was) prone to.

**"Made in the same factory"**

Many of the top Alkaline cells *are* made "in the same factory". There are 3 major Chinese Alkaline battery makers who have the lion's share of world production between them. Other factories can and do make quality cells. GP (Gold Peak)sell under their own brand as well as to others and are well enough known that fake GP labelled cells are a thing.

A 'made elsewhere' cell that is much cheaper than brand name cells is liable to be value for money as long as weight is 11+ grams and Voc is > 1.6V.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about *brands*, then like Barry, I can't say in advance.

In *general*, yes.  Once you've made a cell the best it can possibly be in all other respects, there's still a tradeoff between discharge rate and total capacity.  So if people cared, a cell built specifically to run a clock for as close to ever as possible would have a different construction than a cell built specifically to light a really bright light for a few minutes.

And the "clock forever" cell would have significantly higher capacity *and internal resistance* than the "big light for a little while" cell.

In *specific*, as mentioned, capacity vs. discharge isn't the only tradeoff -- there's those two vs. shelf life, vs. manufacturing cost, vs. the competency and "give a @#$%" of the people building the battery, etc.